# How to fix listview items duplicate, and two Arraylist in one listview in android studio

Tags: android, listview

My Adapter.

```
public class customDecisionAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
                Context context;
                private ArrayList<String> list1;
                private ArrayList<String> list2;

                public customDecisionAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<String>list1, ArrayList<String>list2) {
                    this.context= context;
                    this.list1= list1;
                    this.list2= list2;

                }

                @Override
                public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
                    View convertView =  view;
                    if(convertView==null){
                        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.customedecisio,viewGroup,false);

                    }
                    TextView t1 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textDisease);
                    TextView t2 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textTotal);

                    // Verify value of position not greater than size of ArrayList.
                    if(position < list1.size())
                            t1.setText(list1.get(position));

                    if(position< list2.size())
                         t2.setText(list2.get(position));

                    return convertView;
                }

                @Override
                public int getCount()
                {
                    if(list1.size() < list2.size())
                      return list2.size();
                    else
                       return list1.size();
                }

                @Override
                public Object getItem(int position) {
                    return position;
                }

                @Override
                public long getItemId(int position) {
                    return position;
                }

 }
```

Also when first arraylist size is more than second arraylist size, second arraylist size is duplicating. Or when second arraylist size is more than first arraylist size, first arraylist is duplicating. How to fix. Help me. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try below solution.**

I think there is a problem with your both if conditions.
here you only handle IF part. you should handle ELSE part also.

**NOTE:** The adapters are built to reuse Views when a View is scrolled so that is no longer visible, it can be used for one of the new Views appearing.

```
@Override
    public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
        View convertView = view;
        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.customedecisio, viewGroup, false);

        }
        TextView t1 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textDisease);
        TextView t2 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textTotal);

        // Verify value of position not greater than size of ArrayList.
        if (position < list1.size()) {
            t1.setText(list1.get(position));
        } else {
            t1.setText("");
        }

        if (position < list2.size()) {
            t2.setText(list2.get(position));
        } else {
            t2.setText("");
        }

        return convertView;
    }
```

Comment: please add an explanation of what you did and why it fixes the problem

Comment: it's crashing :((

Comment: send me your crash report. bcz, that is not possible.

Comment: @VishrutMavani sorry, i write wrong place. It's working. Thank you :3

Answer (score 0):

You can use custom ArrayList and getter, setter method for that. Don't use two separate arrayLists. Make one model class as below: -

```
public class Model {
    private String Disease;
    private String Total;

    public Model(String disease, String total) {
        Disease = disease;
        Total = total;
    }

    public String getDisease() {
        return Disease;
    }

    public void setDisease(String disease) {
        Disease = disease;
    }

    public String getTotal() {
        return Total;
    }

    public void setTotal(String total) {
        Total = total;
    }
}



Use List<Model> list = new Arraylist<>();
```

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand. But I two model class   
private List<MembersOne> teamOnes;
        private List<MemberTwo> teamTwos;

Comment: This is not good way to use two arraylist. There should be one arraylist and you can customize your arraylist by defining model class.

Answer (score 0):

```
**You should be using LinkedHashSet if you want to avoid duplicates and maintain order.**

//Your  Wrapper Class

    public class Model {
        private String Disease;
        private String Total;

        public Model(String disease, String total) {
            Disease = disease;
            Total = total;
        }

        public String getDisease() {
            return Disease;
        }

        public void setDisease(String disease) {
            Disease = disease;
        }

        public String getTotal() {
            return Total;
        }

        public void setTotal(String total) {
            Total = total;
        }
    }


//Your Adapter

    public class customDecisionAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
                    Context context;
                    private LinkedHashSet<Model> list1;


                    public customDecisionAdapter(Context context, LinkedHashSet<Model> list1) {
                        this.context= context;
                        this.list1= list1;


                    }

                    @Override
                    public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
                        View convertView =  view;
                        if(convertView==null){
                            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.customedecisio,viewGroup,false);

                        }
                        TextView t1 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textDisease);
                        TextView t2 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textTotal);

                        // Verify value of position not greater than size of ArrayList.

                                t1.setText(list1.get(position).getDisease());


                             t2.setText(list1.get(position).getTotal());

                        return convertView;
                    }

                    @Override
                    public int getCount()
                    {
                           return list1.size();
                    }

                    @Override
                    public Object getItem(int position) {
                        return position;
                    }

                    @Override
                    public long getItemId(int position) {
                        return position;
                    }

     }
// Inside your activity onCreate method

    LinkedHashSet<Model> listset = new LinkedHashSet<Model>();

    listset.add(new Model("Malaria","200"));
    listset.add(new Model("Cold","200"))
    ...//add more items here


    //Then call your adapter and pass this list
    customDecisionAdapter  mAdapter = new customDecisionAdapter(listset,this);
```

Comment: I'm sorry. Must be 2 arraylist.

Comment: may I know why you are using 2 arraylist?

Answer (score -1):

You could just use `Set` as it behaves more less like a list but does not allow duplicates.

```java
public class customDecisionAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
                Context context;
                private Set<String> set = new TreeSet<String>;

                public customDecisionAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<String>list1, ArrayList<String>list2) {
                    this.context= context;
                    this.set.addAll(list1);
                    this.set.addAll(list2);
                }
// rest of the code
```

Comment: I don't think you understand the issue the OP is facing. Also, a HashSet looses the order of the items